# Approach to modeling for a new attribute to attach to exactly one of the many in a one to many relationship

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relationships

Apologies for the awkward title; I wasn't quite sure how to concisely describe what I'm trying to do. My situation goes like this:

- We have a `Product` table in our database;
- Each `Product` may have 0 or more `Foo` objects;
- `Foo` objects are defined in their respective table. As it stands, a `foo` just has an id, a `Product` id, and a variety of `Foo` specific fields.

I am being tasked with adding a new value, `Bar` to the `Foo`'s, however *at most one* `Foo` per `Product` is ever allowed to have a `Bar`.

I was wondering how to best approach modeling this new `Bar` value. One thought I had was to simply add a `bar` column to the `foo` table. I would then probably need to always check for something like `count(Bar) <= 1` for each group of `Foo`'s under a given `Product`.

For some reason, I have a hunch that this isn't the cleanest approach that I could possibly take here. Perhaps due to the fact that I'd be having an entire column that'd be sparsely populated, being filled primarily with `null`. I also feel like, as a user, this might make the process of defining a new `Foo` for a `Product`  more complex, as there will need to be extra validation in place to ensure that a `Bar` isn't being defined when some other `Foo` already has one.

Could there be a better way of modeling this ?

Comment: Is `bar` intrinsically a property of `foo` or can it also be seen as a property of `product`? Your use of generic names, like foo and bar, makes it harder to understand which possible solutions could be acceptable for the requirement you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bar` column in table `Foo`, with an ad-hoc validation, is a perfectly valid solution:

- There is no database impact of there are many `null` values in a column. The main drawback is that an ill-behaved application could break the rule. Unless you enforce it in a DB trigger. But this raises then a more general question about whether or not it is desirable to have a lot of code in the db.
- In fact, in an OO model, a common way to handle simple cases of inheritance (e.g. if Bar would be one of the few extra property of a class derived from Foo) is called [Single Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) and it routinely uses nullable columns in exact this way.

If you want a stronger implementation, you could opt for a slightly more cumbersome model:

- Add a separate `Bar` table
- Its primary key shall be `product id`, so there can be at most one `Bar` per `Product`
- Add a non null `Foo id` as foreign key, so you know to which Foo the Bar belongs, and conversely, you can find the existence or absence of Bar for any given Foo.
- and of course, add the `Bar` column for the content (and perhaps in the future a couple of other properties ?)

This way, you let the database enforce the rule: even unbehaved applications (or worse: a user with an SQL command processor and sufficient credentials) must comply a minimum with your structural rule.

But of course, your application will have to work with an extra table,  so it's a (small) complexity increase.

Comment: Additionally, you could make a composite key from `product_id` and `bar_id` which is the primary key in the `Bar`-table and a foreign key (together with a unique constraint) in the `Foo`-table. So there is only one `Product-Foo` which can have the `product_bar_id` as a foreign key.